# Automapper CustomResolver IMemberValueResolver TDestMember always null

Tags: c#, automapper

When using Automappers IMemberValueResolver for some reason the TDestMember  is always 0 or null, any ideas?

```
      public class CustomResolver : IMemberValueResolver<object, object, int, int>
    {
        public int Resolve(object source, object destination, int sourceMember, int destinationMember, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

An example of how I am calling this:

```
   .ForMember(dest => dest.SortOrder,
    opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CustomResolver, int>(src => src.Id));
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

That happens when you don't pass a destination object to Map.

Comment: Please can you show an example of how this should be passed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Map looks like this:

```
CreateMap<Source, Destination>
    .ForMember(dest => dest.SortOrder)
         opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CustomResolver, int>(src => src.Id));
```

And your CustomResolver looks like this:

```
public class CustomResolver : IMemberValueResolver<Source, Destination, int, int>
{
     public int Resolve(Source source, Destination destination, int sourceMember, int destinationMember, ResolutionContext context)
     {
         return 1;
     }
}
```

*TDestMember* (the `destinationMember` parameter) will be null or default value inside your resolver because it has not been mapped yet.  The `sourceMember` parameter will be the value of the predicate in your map (`src => src.Id`).

Typmically, you would only use an `IMemberValueResolver<>` when you need to pass a specific value in the predicate needed in your resolve logic.  Otherwise, if you only need the source and/or destination objects you would use a `IValueResolver<>` instead.